# Open windows in center of screen

Tags: window, window-management

I'd like to have all of my windows open in the center of my screen instead of the top left corner. Is this possible? If so, where do I configure this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using Gnome with Compiz, install CompizConfig Settings Manager.

- You can find it here:

[image]

- Or install it via Terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Then open it and go to Window Management > Place Windows, enable it, and in "Placement Mode" choose Centered.

Comment: `compiz` has been removed from Debian, as [mentioned here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111115/no-installation-candidate-for-compiz).

Answer (score 24):

For newer version of gnome (3.14 or higher) compiz has been removed.
you can now Open windows in center of screen by check `center-new-windows` in `/org/gnome/mutter/` using `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Does that work for Unity as well?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it works out of the box and is just a small change.

Comment: Actually I opened a bug report to make this setting the default: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/246 IMHO, everything else makes no sense. Feel free to upvote it. :)

Comment: the perfect answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Actually, in recent versions of Ubuntu it is enabled by default. And since GNOME v3.30 there is also a visible option in [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks):

[image: GNOME Tweaks with Windows->"Center New Windows" highlighted]

Just select "Center New Windows" under "Windows".

Comment: Since this, and the original answer, both involve tweak tools I’m leaving the original answer as the main one. Yours is still a valued answer. Thank you

Comment: @Frantumn No, they  don't both involve tweak tools. "Compiz" is a whole new window manager and a lot more. My answer is a nearly built-in tool in GNOME that just extends the settings. Using "Compiz" is a complicated workaround that I am not sure whether it still works anyway in recent Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Also see my comment: "in recent versions of Ubuntu it is enabled by default". As such the whole question is more or less obsolete now.

Comment: BTW, in contrast to what i said, (that it's the default in Ubuntu now) this topic is not dead and still in discussion in [Fedora](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/should-gnome-center-new-windows-by-default-or-not/1413?u=rugk) & [Ubuntu](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/center-windows-by-default/10262?u=rugk).

Comment: this was disabled in ubuntu 20.04 lts for some reason