# In Unity, how can I make application windows open in the center of the screen?

Tags: 16.04, window-manager, window

For Gnome [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/776438/403828) seems to work to center opened application windows horizontally and vertically. Does Ubuntu Unity 16.04 have a similar feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What yo need is CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM):

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt install compiz-plugins
```

then open CCSM by going to the dash and type CCSM:
[image]

then go to Window management and window placement:

[image]

and play around till you've got exactly what you want!

Comment: Great! Tab `General` actually allows you to set `Centered` as the default.

Comment: :D  It has a ton of possibilities!  I knew it existed but was too lazy to find it exactly. Favour returned, question upvoted! @RobertOrzanna

Comment: And solution found. :-)